# jQuery Datatables - Using SELECT and RESPONSIVE - Problem with ON SELECT event

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using SELECT and RESPONSIVE extension together in the same table.

The user will be redirected when it clicks on a table row....

```
grid.on('select', function (e, dt, type, indexes) {

        var rowData = grid.rows(indexes).data().toArray();
        //console.log('rowData');

        //console.log(rowData);

        var id = rowData[0][0];
        //console.log(id);

        onChange(id);
 });

    function onChange(rId) {

        window.location.hash = 'show/' + rId;

    }
```

The problem is that when I have the RESPONSIVE extension on....

When the user clicks on the "+" icon, to show the row details, it triggers the above "on select" event... instead of showing the row content

Is there a way to stop that behavior ? Like, if the user clicks on the "+" button the "on select" event is not triggered ... Or someway to check, inside the "on select" function that will stop that function...

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

This code did the trick ! The first column is hidden, and only it is only shown when the table gets colapsed...

```
   responsive: {
        details: {
            type: 'column'
        }
    },
    select: {
        style: 'os',
        selector: 'td:not(:first-child)'
    },
    columnDefs: [
        {
            className: 'control',
            searchable: false,
            orderable: false,
            targets: [0]
        }]
```